# Discovering the derivatives of functions combined with trig values.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Hey StackExchange I have a problem that I don't really understand and I could use some hints for starting it.

Suppose $m(\frac{\pi}{3}) = 4$ and $ m'(\frac{\pi}{3}) = -2$, and let $g(x) = m(x)\sin x$ and $h(x) = \frac{\cos x}{m(x)}$. Find $g'(\frac{\pi}{3})$ and $h'(\frac{\pi}{3})$.

I'm really not sure how to go about solving this problem, can I discover what $m$ is from its value and derivative and $\pi$ over $3$?

Comment: Oh wait perhaps I just need to plug in values with the product rule? Let me try...

Comment: That is exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to find $g'$ and $h'$, seems reasonable to differentiate the expressions the exercise has given you. We have $$g'(x) = m'(x)~\sin(x) + m(x)~\cos x$$
and also $$h'(x) = \frac{-\sin(x)~m(x) - \cos x~m'(x)}{(m(x))^2}$$
Now you can plug $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and solve the system for $g'(\pi/3)$ and $h'(\pi/3)$. Ok?